# Is there any explicit description of the maximal totally ramified extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, local-fields

It is well known that the maximal unramified extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ can be extended by adding the roots of unity of order prime to $p$. Is there any explicit description of the maximal totally ramified extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$?

Comment: A composite of totally ramified extensions need not be totally ramified, so there is no *the* maximal totally ramified extension. Lubin–Tate theory gives a field that behaves like a maximal totally ramified *abelian* extension, but I'm not sure if you can say much beyond the abelian case.

Comment: A more elementary version of @R.vanDobbendeBruyn's excellent response:  there's not even any single totally ramified field containing all totally ramified, *quadratic* extensions; with $p \ne 2$, any field containing both $\mathbb Q_p(\sqrt p)$ and $\mathbb Q_p(\sqrt{\epsilon p})$, where $\epsilon$ is a non-square unit in $\mathbb Q_p$, both of which are totally ramified over $\mathbb Q_p$, contains $\mathbb Q_p(\sqrt\epsilon)$, which is unramified over $\mathbb Q_p$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A composite of totally ramified extensions need not be totally ramified:

**Example 1.** (As per LSpice's suggestion) Consider the extensions $\mathbb Q_p(\sqrt{p})$ and $\mathbb Q_p(\sqrt{\varepsilon p})$, where $\varepsilon \in \mathbb Z_p^\times$ is a nonsquare unit (corresponding, for example, to any lift of a generator of $\mathbb F_p^\times$). Then the compositum $\mathbb Q_p(\sqrt{p},\sqrt{\varepsilon p})$ contains the unramified extension $\mathbb Q_p(\sqrt{\varepsilon})$.

**Example 2.** Consider the extension $\mathbb Q_p \subseteq \mathbb Q_p(\sqrt[n]{p})$, where $n = p^r - 1$. Then the Galois closure of this extension contains all $n$-th roots of unity. But $\mathbb Q_p \subseteq \mathbb Q_p(\zeta_{p^r-1})$ is the unique degree $r$ unramified extension. Thus, we see that the Galois closure of a totally ramified extension need not even be totally ramified.

So there is no such thing as *the* maximal totally ramified extension. You could in principle still construct some maximal totally ramified extension (i.e. no further extension is totally ramified), but as far as I can tell these fields are not very explicit. By the second example above, it is not a Galois extension of $\mathbb Q_p$.

On the other hand, maximal *abelian* totally ramified extensions are very well studied: Lubin–Tate theory gives a relatively explicit construction of an abelian field extension $K \to K^{\operatorname{LT}}$ that is linearly disjoint from $K^{\operatorname{ab}}_{\operatorname{nr}}$ such that their compositum equals $K^{\operatorname{ab}}$. Thus, $K^{\operatorname{LT}}$ plays the role of a maximal abelian totally ramified extension in a relatively strong sense. The most explicit case is $K=\mathbb Q_p$; in this case we have $K^{\operatorname{LT}} = \mathbb Q_p(\zeta_{p^\infty})$.

Comment: You should be able to construct a maximal totally ramified extension of $\mathbf{Q}_p$ by picking some $g$ in the absolute Galois group of $\mathbf{Q}_p$ whose image in the absolute Galois group of $\mathbf{F}_p$ generates it, and then taking for your extension $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}_p^{\langle g \rangle}$.